# How do I merge a Signal and a SignalProducer into a Signal in ReactiveSwift?

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, reactive-swift

How do I merge a Signal and a SignalProducer into a Signal in ReactiveSwift?

Below is what I have so far. I can't figure out how to get a `Signal` on line 3.

```
let (signalA, observerA) = Signal<String, NoError>.pipe()
let signalProducer = /* some signalproducer */
let signalFromSignalProducer == /* how to get a signal from signalProducer here??? */
let mergedSignal = Signal.merge([signalA, signalFromSignalProducer])
```

I've looked at this `startWithSignal` method

```
 public func startWithSignal(_ setup: (ReactiveSwift.Signal<Value, Error>, Disposable) -> Swift.Void)
```

but it takes a closure. Why can't it just return a signal? I don't want to have to create another nested closure for every signalProducer i need the signal from. What.

I'm new to ReactiveSwift and honestly this is the most confusing framework I've ever came across

Comment: `startWithSignal` takes a closure so that you can wire up the produced signal before before it starts sending any events. If it just returned a signal, it would be possible to miss events in between the time you call `start` and the time you hook it up, depending on the producer in question. Can you add some more detail about what you're trying to do here? There may a more idiomatic way of setting this up that doesn't require using `startWithSignal` like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reactive-Swift has a [`start` overload that takes an observer as a parameter](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveSwift/blob/1.1.3/Sources/SignalProducer.swift#L224), so I think you can achieve the same effect as `merge` by calling `signalProducer.start(observerA)`. That should send all of the produced signal's events through `signalA`.

As for why it's done this way: `startWithSignal` takes a closure so that you can wire up the produced signal before before it starts sending any events. If it just returned a signal, it would be possible to miss events in between the time you call start and the time you hook it up, depending on the producer in question. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35617971/642233) gives an example of this.